# Remove appended script on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to do is when the browser window width is above 992px, to enable the script DOUBLE TAP TO GO for the menu. But when the browser window width becomes less than 992px to disable DOUBLE TAP TO GO script, because I want a single tap to go for the hamburger menu.

I managed to do this when the window is more than 992px... But when I switch my iPad to portrait mode (which is less than 992px) the DOUBLE TAP TO GO script is still active because there was no refresh on the page.

So when orientation changes I run the code.

Can you tell me how can I remove the DOUBLE TAP GO script on else? I can't find a way...

**MY CODE**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    orientationChange();
});

function orientationChange() {
    if(window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        if(window.matchMedia("(min-width: 992px)").matches) {   

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 1) DOUBLE TAP TO GO

(function( $, window, document, undefined )
{
    $.fn.doubleTapToGo = function( params )
    {
        if( !( 'ontouchstart' in window ) &&
            !navigator.msMaxTouchPoints &&
            !navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match( /windows phone os 7/i ) ) return false;

        this.each( function()
        {
            var curItem = false;

            $( this ).on( 'click', function( e )
            {
                var item = $( this );
                if( item[ 0 ] != curItem[ 0 ] )
                {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    curItem = item;
                }
            });

            $( document ).on( 'click touchstart MSPointerDown', function( e )
            {
                var resetItem = true,
                    parents   = $( e.target ).parents();

                for( var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++ )
                    if( parents[ i ] == curItem[ 0 ] )
                        resetItem = false;

                if( resetItem )
                    curItem = false;
            });
        });
        return this;
    };
})( jQuery, window, document );


    jQuery( function()
    {
        jQuery( '#menu-top-menu li' ).doubleTapToGo();
    });
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
            }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

          else {

              //REMOVE DOUBLE TAP SCRIPT FROM MEMORY


               }



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////         
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to set and reset your  click handlers on window's orientationchange event. Which is trigerred everytime the orientation changes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientationchange_event

Comment: Can you show me how? Because I have no idea... -Thanks